# What context Should be Use in setUserVisibleHint Method

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

Because All fragment loaded with together In Pager Sliding tab , I need to use `setUserVisibleHint()` for laoding that fragment selected .
I have Problem with Context in the `setUserVisibleHint()` method :
It raised `NPE Exception` when I use `getActivity` for my Context. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Because **getActivity** will return null before fragment **attached** to Activity you need check this value will null or check fragment attached to activity or after **onActivityActtached** function.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
       //do something
    }
} 

//or 
 boolean isAttached = false;
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        isAttached = true;
    }

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isAttached) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: and if getActivity returned null what should i work for preventing that ?

Comment: you should waiting or anything that not use actvity because fragment don't have a activity

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use newInstance Method and put your String over there. And then in fragment use

```
getArguments().getString("KEY")
```